# Keras Tokenizer: random results due to different mapping of text tokens and IDs

Tags: keras, tokenize

I am training a neural network in Keras. I am using its Tokenizer function like this:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(filters='')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(words)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)
```

Unfortunately each time I run the code the mapping between text tokens and IDs is different. So if I want to load a saved model I'll get different results each time.

How can I get the same Tokenizer for both training and running the model?

Comment: maybe I'm missing something obvious, but why can't you just pickle the tokenizer and save it along with the model?

Comment: this is exactly what I did, and it works. Still it doesn't seem reasonable that this is the right way to do it and no one documented it. Also, there is no reason for the Tokenizer to have a new random mapping every time and the only way to even notice it is when you try to test your saved model in another program and see that it gives random results.