# Reloading Keras Tokenizer during Testing

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tokenize, text-classification, word-embedding

I followed the tutorial here: (https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html)

However, I modified the code to be able to save the generated model through `h5py`. Thus, after running the training script, I have a generated `model.h5` in my directory.

Now, when I want to load it, my problem is that I'm confused as to how to re-initiate the `Tokenizer`. The tutorial has the following line of code:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(nb_words=MAX_NB_WORDS)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)
```

But hypothetically, if I reload the `model.h5` in a different module, I'll need to create another `Tokenizer` to tokenize the test set. But then, the new `Tokenizer` will be fit on the test data thus creating a completely different word table.

Therefore, my question is: How do I reload the `Tokenizer` that was trained on the training dataset? Am I in some way misunderstanding the functionality of the `Embedding` layer in Keras? Right now, I'm assuming that since we mapped certain word indices to their corresponding embedding vectors based on the pre-trained word embeddings, the word indices need to be consistent. However, this is not possible if we perform another `fit_on_texts` on the test dataset.

Thank you and looking forward to your answers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras Text Preprocessing - Saving Tokenizer object to file for scoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735070/keras-text-preprocessing-saving-tokenizer-object-to-file-for-scoring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758405/keras-tokenizer-random-results-due-to-different-mapping-of-text-tokens-and-ids) 
The commenter recommends using a pickle to save the object & state, though the question still remains why this kind of functionality is not built into keras.