# Loaded keras model in flask always predict same class

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, flask, keras

Weird thing is happening to me. I trained a sentiment analysis model using keras as follows:

```
max_fatures = 2000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_fatures, split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data)
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data)
X = pad_sequences(X)

with open('tokenizer.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    _pickle.dump(tokenizer, fid)

le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(["pos", "neg"])
y = le.transform(data_labels)
y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y)

embed_dim = 128
lstm_out = 196

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_fatures, embed_dim, input_length=X.shape[1]))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.4))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_out, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 32
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2)

model.save('deep.h5')
```

When I load it in another python file, everything is fine. But when I load it inside a flask web application, all predicted classes are positive. What is going wrong? Here is the code that I use in my flask web application:

```
with open('./resources/model/tokenizer.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
    keras_tokenizer = _pickle.load(handle)

K.clear_session()
model = load_model('./resources/model/deep.h5')
model._make_predict_function()
session = K.get_session()
global graph
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
graph.finalize()

stop_words = []

with open('./resources/stopwords.txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    stop_words = f.read().splitlines()

normalizer = Normalizer()
stemmer = Stemmer()
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')


def predict_class(text):
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    temp = ''

    for token in tokens:
        if token in stop_words:
            continue

        token = normalizer.normalize(token)
        token = stemmer.stem(token)
        temp += token + ' '

    if not temp.strip():
        return None

    text = keras_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(temp.strip())
    text = pad_sequences(text, maxlen=41)

    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(["pos", "neg"])

    with session.as_default():
        with graph.as_default():
            sentiment = model.predict_classes(text)
            return le.inverse_transform(sentiment)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the model architecture but not it's weights!

Given that you are using Keras and its tokenizer, I have found that the best way to load and reuse your models is to use the json representation for the architecture and the tokenizer and save the weights with h5:

```
def save(model):
    # Save the trained weights
    model.save_weights('model_weights.h5')

    # Save the model architecture
    with open('model_architecture.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(model.to_json())

    # Save the tokenizer
    with open('tokenizer.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(tokenizer.to_json())
```

Then at your flask app load them like this:

```
def models():
    with open('models/tokenizer.json') as f:
        tokenizer = tokenizer_from_json(f.read())

    # Model reconstruction from JSON file
    with open('models/model_architecture.json', 'r') as f:
        model = model_from_json(f.read())

    # Load weights into the new model
    model.load_weights('models/model_weights.h5')

    return model, tokenizer
```

Comment: I tried this but still get only positive class from the model.

Comment: Hmmm, it's strange, I'm using this approach right now in one of my projects and works fine. Are you saving the weights after the training of the model (model.fit)? Try to print model.get_weights() after loading the weights and check that are properly loaded!

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I had the same issue. But in my case, my predictions were correct. I figured that ".h5" files with model architecture and weights were not sufficient, you need to have the tokenizer because it contains the word index of all the unique tokens or words on which your model was trained on.

So, therefore, I would highly recommend (Eudald Arranz)[https://stackoverflow.com/users/11153431/eudald-arranz] 's Last Post On this thread - to save with JSON format the weights and model architecture.

Post: [Loaded keras model in flask always predict same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56004287/loaded-keras-model-in-flask-always-predict-same-class)

Cause This actually worked for me.

Thanks, Eudald

Answer (score 0):

Tokenizer class has a function to save date into JSON format:

```
tokenizer_json = tokenizer.to_json()
with io.open('tokenizer.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(tokenizer_json, ensure_ascii=False))
```

The data can be loaded using tokenizer_from_json function from keras_preprocessing.text:

```
with open('tokenizer.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    tokenizer = tokenizer_from_json(data)
```

Thanks to Max, at [Keras Text Preprocessing - Saving Tokenizer object to file for scoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735070/keras-text-preprocessing-saving-tokenizer-object-to-file-for-scoring)