# How to save one hot encoder?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to save a one hot encoder from keras to use it again on different texts but keeping the same encoding.

Here is my code :

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv ')
vocab_size = 200000
encoded_docs = [one_hot(d, vocab_size) for d in df.text]
```

How can I save this encoder and use it again later ?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735070/keras-text-preprocessing-saving-tokenizer-object-to-file-for-scoring) in my research but one_hot() seems to be a function and not an object (sorry if this is plain wrong I am fairly new to python).

Comment: Won't pickling it work? I.e. `import pickle; with open("encoder", "wb") as f: pickle.dump(one_hot, f)`. Functions are objects, too.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, your code works and i am able to save it to a file, but how can I restore and re-use it ?

Comment: `import pickle; with open("encoder", "rb") as f: one_hot = pickle.load(f)`

Comment: Thanks again but when I do `encoder = pickle.load(f)` and then after `encoded_docs =[encoder(d, vocab_size) for d in df.text]` the encoding seems different, as if I retrained the encoder with this line.

Comment: How exactly is `one_hot` created?

Comment: Its imported : `from.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot` and its first and only usage in code is the one I showed in the original question : `encoded_docs = [one_hot(d, vocab_size) for d in df.text]`.

Comment: Aha! This supposed encoding is cheating, it's using `hash()` to generate quasi-unique encodings. Due to hash seed randomization, the numbers will always be different. Start Python with `PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python`, then it should work (and you don't need to pickle the function, just import it).

Comment: Hum interesting answer ! What would you recommend using in my case to feed texts to an embedding layer ?

Comment: I usually use [sklearn's OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) for this. I think this is out of scope for this question, though. The solution in my last comment should work.

Comment: That's true, thanks again !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mentioning the Answer in this Section (although it is present in Comments Section), for the benefit of the Community.

To Save the Encoder, you can use the below code:

```
import pickle
with open("encoder", "wb") as f: 
    pickle.dump(one_hot, f)
```

Then to Load the Saved Encoder, use the below code:

```
encoder = pickle.load(f) 
encoded_docs =[encoder(d, vocab_size) for d in df.text]
```

Since the function, `from.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot` uses `hash()` to generate quasi-unique encodings, we need to use a `HashSeed` for reproducing our Results (getting same result even after multiple executions).

Run the below code in the Terminal, for Setting the `HashSeed`:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The previous answer is awesome, and I find another available option which needs joblib

```
from joblib import dump, load
dump(clf, 'filename.joblib') # save the model
clf = load('filename.joblib') # load and reuse the model
```