# How to get access to tokenzier after loading a saved custom BERT model using Keras and TF2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tokenize, bert-language-model

I am working on Intent classification problem and need your help.

I fine-tuned one of the BERT model for text classification. Trained and evaluated it on a small dataset for detecting five intents. I used the following code [Intent Recognition with BERT using Keras and TensorFlow 2](https://curiousily.com/posts/intent-recognition-with-bert-using-keras-and-tensorflow-2/) It is working fine!
[image]
I have saved the model, so that I can use later on without retraining the model again in future.

```
# Save the entire model as a SavedModel.
!mkdir -p saved_model
model.save('saved_model/intentclassifiermodel')
```

And zipped it and downloaded it to use it separately

```
!zip -r saved_model.zip saved_model/
```

Now, I am trying to use this model to predict the intent recognition. For that I created another google colab notebook and loaded the model

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

!pip install tensorflow==2.2

!pip install bert-for-tf2 >> /dev/null

import bert

from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/NLPMODELS/saved_model/intentclassifiermodel')

model.summary()
```

[image]

The model is loaded successfully, now I want to predict. For that I am using following code snippet (it was the same code in base code)

```
sentences = [
  
  "are you a bot?",
  "how to create a bot"
]

pred_tokens = map(tokenizer.tokenize, sentences)
pred_tokens = map(lambda tok: ["[CLS]"] + tok + ["[SEP]"], pred_tokens)
pred_token_ids = list(map(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids, pred_tokens))

pred_token_ids = map(lambda tids: tids +[0]*(data.max_seq_len-len(tids)),pred_token_ids)
pred_token_ids = np.array(list(pred_token_ids))

predictions = model.predict(pred_token_ids).argmax(axis=-1)

for text, label in zip(sentences, predictions):
  print("text:", text, "\nintent:", classes[label])
  print()
```

**However, this code fails because I am not sure how to access the tokenizer here. **

Here is the error
[image]

*Can you please help me how to get the tokenizer?*

Thanks and Regards,
Rohit Dhamija

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735070/keras-text-preprocessing-saving-tokenizer-object-to-file-for-scoring

Comment: @AloneTogether thanks, but it seems the answers are old and not relevant today. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AloneTogether so do we need two assets - model folder and tokenizer.pickle file? I thought the model will have everything that we need.

Comment: Nope..the model does not have the tokenizer.

Comment: @AloneTogether Thanks, i will try and then update here in couple of hours!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239776/discussion-between-rohit-and-alonetogether).

Comment: @AloneTogether Thanks! I am able to make it work!

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you @AloneTogether for pointing out to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735070/keras-text-preprocessing-saving-tokenizer-object-to-file-for-scoring)

So, besides saving the model assest folder, I also saved the tokenizer.

In order to make the code work, I required two additional things

data.max_seq_len and class values.

For now, I extracted them while saving the model and used it in my program.

Thanks!